# Which architectural pattern allows dynamic instantiation of multiple views per model?

Tags: model-view-controller

Let's say I want to build a calendar app (in HTML + JS) where the user can see one week at a time.

The user should be able to define events, e.g. Mondays from 1:00 - 3:00:

```
         +---------+---------+     +---------+
         | Monday  | Tuesday | ... |  Sunday |
         +---------+---------+     +---------+
0:00     |         |         |     |         |
         +---------+---------+     +---------+
1:00     ///////////         |     |         |
         //MyEvent//---------+     +---------+
2:00     ///////////         |     |         |
         +---------+---------+     +---------+
...                                   
         +---------+                  ...
23:00    |         |   ...
         +---------+
```

I thought about creating one model, `EventModel` and one view, `EventView`, and wiring them up by the usual MVC approach. An `eventView` would be rendered on top of the calendar grid as a separate layer, so it would be able to autonomously maintain its size and position.
`EventModel` has nothing but three attributes, `startTime`, `duration` and `title`.

Things become more difficult though, if the user defines an event that spans over midnight, like Mondays 23:00 - Tuesdays 2:00:

```
         +---------+---------+     +---------+
         | Monday  | Tuesday | ... |  Sunday |
         +---------+---------+     +---------+
0:00     |         ///////////     |         |
         +---------//MyEvent//     +---------+
1:00     |         ///////////     |         |
         +---------+---------+     +---------+
2:00     |         |         |     |         |
         +---------+---------+     +---------+
...                                   
         +---------+                  ...
23:00    //MyEvent//   ...
         +---------+
```

Now two views bound to the same model are needed.

Naturally, all changes in the model should be reflected in the view(s). Note that the number of views required for a single model may change (1 to 7) as the `startTime` or `duration` attributes are updated.

In other words: **Changes in the model need to trigger instantiation/destruction of views for that model.**

I see two possible approaches for achieving this:

- Use some controller logic that dynamically generates/deletes the required number of views and models, and keeps the models in sync with each other

... which seems like a bad idea since that would require a lot of fumbling as well as an additional class of models.

**or**

- Stick with one model and build a View proxy that acts like one view, but internally controls the required number of "subviews".

The second approach is much more appealing to me. I wrote some pseudo-code to illustrate it:

```
ViewProxy.onModelChange(model) {
    if (model.hasChanged("startTime") or model.hasChanged("duration"))
        this.destroySubviews()
        subStartTimes[] = getSubStartTimes(model.startTime, model.duration)
        subDurations[] = getSubDurations(model.startTime, model.duration)
        subViews[] = this.buildSubviews(subStartTimes, subDurations)
        subViews.bind(model, "title")
    endif
}
```

The downside with this is that the subviews unnecessarily get destroyed and re-built on all model updates (except `title` only), unless I include additional logic - which is not so trivial. Also, this proxy is some weird thing between controller and view, which somehow makes me feel uncomfortable.

So my question is: Is there a standard approach to this problem? If not, which issues may arise with the above solution? Any other solutions?

Comment: That pattern is called "MVC" (as opposed to Rails-like structure, which you seem to be implementing now). Model is supposed to be an application later. Kinda like views, template, presentation objects and controllers are contained in the presentation layer.

Comment: Any MVC that uses a template engine or an "untemplated engine" (E.G php code inside your views as part of a view class) will support you passing in parameters from the controller / model this then allows you to use this information to build the view however you want to using includes or just processing the same as php other than the values it needs are passed in from controller or model, some MVC's support you loading a view from a model and returning it as html, so if the view is doing application layer stuff it can be part of the model.

Comment: i know the comment i have used php as an example however this works for anything in Java for example your template could be your window as standard and window components from your model/controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around for a while, I found that the answer is [*The Composite Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

So, the idea is to treat all the event view snippets of one events as a single view that manages several subviews. 
As for data binding, I guess this is not possible without a bit of logic in the view. In my case, I decided that the view itself would be composed (think *Composite* pattern!) of a smaller MVC hierarchy. So the models inside the view are bound to the subviews by simple data binding, and the ViewProxy manages updates in the underlying model.

Answer (score 1):

Your `EventModel` maps to multiple View elements because your model contains multiple sub elements (`EventDayModel`).

Sure, the input definition of the `EventModel` might be `title`, `startDateTime`, `duration`, but the model conceptually consists of one or more `EventDayModel` elements (each containing a `startTime` and `duration`).

So instead of maintaining a one to one mapping between the `EventModel` and the `EventViewProxy` (which effectively controls the view elements corresponding to each day), why not just subdivide the `EventModel` into a list of `EventDayModel`, each which have a one to one mapping to `EventDayView` elements.

When you change an `EventModel`, it's `EventDayModel` list is recalculated and the corresponding `EventDayView` elements are updated.

Comment: ok, but who or what takes care of instantiation/destruction of additional views? Remember that 1 EventModel may correspond to 1 to 7 EventDadModel instances, depending on `startDateTime` and `duration`. At the end of the day, you're gonna end up with something like EventViewProxy

Comment: Well, assuming you are using a MVC framework, then the MVC framework is responsible. For example, using `AngularJS`, you will use an `ng-repeat` to bind the `event.evenDays` list so that each eventDay is display in a view element (a `<div>` for example). If the list changes, `AngularJS` add/removes the view elements.

Comment: Try and code that with AngularJS. It may be possible, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score -2):

You could emulate Google Calendar structure which re-renders the calendar rather than destroying and recreating subviews.

If you use Angular then you could tie up scope variables and put a watch on the model attributes to update the view properties.

Each view could be seen as "div box" positioned depending on the start and end times. If the user deletes the event then the associated "div box" and the event object is removed from list of events.

If there is an update with to event then we update the coordinates of the "div box" depending start and endtimes.

The resource below is to show the model structure used by google calendar.

> https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/package-summary.html

Comment: Not sure how that answers the question

Comment: I looked into the Google Calendar Webapp, and found that they apparently circumvent the problem by treating the whole week as one view. So each time you change an event, the whole calendar is re-rendered. Which is not what I want ;)

Comment: My apologies for the incomplete answer before as I was caught up on some other activities, please see my updated answer - clarified.